# Blade Query with multiple where and orWhere clause matching certain id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a laravel project that I want to check if the user either owners or rents a property from a MySQLDB, I have a rewrite rule that allows them to visit a page and edit this property

```
Route::get('/housing/manage/{id}', function() {
        return view('pages.housing_management.housing_management');
    });
```

Now, I have this query that checks if they either own or rent it, but thats to check if theres any properties that match that rule, is where a way I can make sure that they own or rent the propertie with id = {id} that is sent with the page?

```
@if (count(Properties::where('owner', '=', Auth::user()->id)->orWhere('rented_by', '=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(1)->get()) > 0)
<p>Authentication Passed, you either own or rent this property.</p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best practice for this case is adding two relations in the User Model to the Properties Model - Like this:

```
public function ownedProperties() {
    return $this->hasMany(Properties::class, 'owner');
}

public function rentedProperties() {
    return $this->hasMany(Properties::class, 'rented_by');
}
```

And then your check is gonna be something like this:

```
@if ($user->ownedProperties->contains($propertyId) || $user->rentedProperties->contains($propertyId))
   <p>Authentication Passed, you either own or rent this property.</p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be written in `routes.php` file as:

```
Route::get('/housing/manage/{id}', function($id) {
        $exists = Properties::where('id', '=', $id)
                            ->where(function($q) {
                                $q->where('owner', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                                    ->orWhere('rented_by', '=', Auth::user()->id);
                            })->exists()
        return view('pages.housing_management.housing_management', compact('exists'));
    });
```

And in your blade file, you can write as:

```
@if ($exists)
<p>Authentication Passed, you either own or rent this property.</p>
@endif
```

Comment: Undefined variable $property_id, is there a way I can fix this? getting the id passed with the url.